# Application crashes when clicked despite being installed on simulators

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, expo-build

I've set up with Expo for iOS and Android, and even though there are no error logs appearing, when I try to install and test the app on the Android emulator or iOS simulator, the application is closing automatically. Please help?

**
app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "AtestTest",
    "slug": "Atest",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.system.Atest"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.system.Atest"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "746b4513-47fc-428a-8eb7-558c86dcc14f"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**eas.json iOS
**

```
{
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

**eas.json Android
**

```
{
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```